# How can I make Firefox load JavaScript from the command line?

Tags: firefox

At the command line I can load websites like this:

```
firefox.exe google.com
```

However, what I am trying to load is the following:

```
javascript:q=document.getSelection();d='U';c=document.characterSet;if(c=='Shift_JIS')d='S';if(c=='EUC-JP')d='D';if(!q){void(q=prompt('Enter%20text%20to%20search%20using%20WWWJDIC%20(Japanese).',''))};if(q)location.href='http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/cgi-bin/wwwjdic.cgi?1M'+d+'J'+q
```

This will load if I paste it in the address bar of firefox, but it will not load if I specify it as an argument from the command line. How can I make it load from the command line?

Comment: At least in windows, the problem is made more complicated by the fact that both the 'run' command and shortcuts limit the number of characters allowed to less than the code you want to run takes.

Comment: As the answer hasn't been accepted yet, did my solution work?

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: It works for me, either the mistake is with encapsulation or you're trying to do too much. Which brings me to the question: What are you trying to do?

Comment: If it works for you then you should know what it does.

Answer (score 8):

Encapsulating it with double quotes works for me:

```
firefox "javascript:alert('Hello World')"
```

Comment: Tried the above on my browser from the Linux Bash prompt and it brought up a page with the "javascript:alert('Hello World')" text in the address bar, but did not execute it. My User Agent is: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686 on x86_64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0.  So how do we get it to execute? I'm running Firefox from the command line so Firefox should just execute it, right?

Comment: @bgoodr Add `-new-window`. It will launch a new window and execute the JS. Only problem is that JS with `window` object will not execute as `window` object is null when the window is launching.

Comment: Though theoretically it should be "--new-window" the parameter provided by @ADTC  works on palemoon. However, it doesn't on the modern Firefox 112

Answer (score -3):

From [HowTo: Run Firefox From The Command Line](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-run-firefox-from-the-command-line/):

> You can use command line as follows with special arguments to start Mozilla Firefox.
>
> To open the browser, enter:
>
> ```
> firefox
> ```
>
> OR
>
> ```
> /usr/bin/firefox
> ```
>
> #### Firefox Open URL
>
> To open URL in a new tab, enter:
>
> ```
> /usr/bin/firefox -new-window http://www.cyberciti.biz/
> ```
>
> To open URL in a new window, enter:
>
> ```
> /usr/bin/firefox www.cyberciti.biz
> ```
>
> #### Firefox Search option
>
> You can search words (term) with your default search engine, enter:
>
> ```
> /usr/bin/firefox -search "term"
> /usr/bin/firefox -search "linux add user to group"
> ```
>
> #### Open Firefox Options / Preferences
>
> To open Firefox options/preferences window, enter:
>
> ```
> /usr/bin/firefox -preferences
> ```
>
> #### Set Firefox As Default Browser
>
> To set the Firefox app as the default browser, enter:
>
> ```
> /usr/bin/firefox -setDefaultBrowser
> ```

Comment: Next time, please don't just copy and paste content from other sites. Link to them, and quote everything you didn't write yourself. Thank you. Plus, you're not really answering the question – this is not what the OP wanted.